# EXC_BREAKPOINT crash in CFReadStreamRead

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, crash

Anyone know why this *sometimes* crashes? I'm stumped on this one. I guess it crashes 1 time in 100 or something like that.

```
// from header file
struct _PTP_IP_Packet_INIT_EVENT_ACK {
    uint32_t ptpIPPacketLength;
    uint32_t ptpIPType;
};
typedef struct _PTP_IP_Packet_INIT_EVENT_ACK      PTP_IP_Packet_INIT_EVENT_ACK;
#define PTP_IP_PacketLength_INIT_EVENT_ACK        (2*sizeof(uint32_t))
```

Crash is on last line:

```
    PTP_IP_Packet_INIT_EVENT_ACK eventack;
    PTP_CNT_INIT(eventack);
    len = [self.myWorker.eventInputStream read:(unsigned char*)&eventack maxLength:PTP_IP_PacketLength_INIT_EVENT_ACK];
```

Crash data:

```
#24
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000184045750
Crashed: PTPWork-192.168.1.1
0  CoreFoundation                 0x184045750 CFHash + 256
1  CoreFoundation                 0x184046c1c CFBasicHashGetCountOfKey + 960
2  CoreFoundation                 0x184046810 CFSetContainsValue + 152
3  CoreFoundation                 0x18407644c CFRunLoopRemoveSource + 236
4  CFNetwork                      0x183b68fcc SocketStream::read(__CFReadStream*, unsigned char*, long, CFStreamError*, unsigned char*) + 520
5  CoreFoundation                 0x184072c88 CFReadStreamRead + 520
6  Photobooth                     0x1001348a0 -[PTPCamera initializeEventStreams] (PTPCamera.m:188)
7  Photobooth                     0x100134398 -[PTPCamera initializePTP] (PTPCamera.m:127)
8  Photobooth                     0x1001084b0 -[PTPWorker setState:] (PTPWorker.m:333)
9  Photobooth                     0x100107b8c -[PTPWorker main] (PTPWorker.m:222)
10 Foundation                     0x18505e308 __NSThread__main__ + 1072
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x195babdc8 _pthread_body + 164
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x195babd24 _pthread_body + 158
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x195ba8ef8 thread_start + 4
```

Answer (score 4):

EXC_BREAKPOINT in this sort of context generally means that an NSException was thrown, which is a handy place for debuggers to break.

The two likeliest reasons (not mutually exclusive) for something to go wrong with self.myWorker.eventInputStream are

- You're trying to read from it after its source was closed
- There's a thread contention issue with that source

That this is crashing in an NSThread makes the second option probable. That you report this happening "1 time in 100 or something like that" makes the second option a virtual certainty.

Just to be sure, put everything using self.myWorker.eventInputStream on the main thread. If crashes immediately disappear completely, as would be expected, then you need to figure out how to properly lock access to the stream so that whatever the contention issue is here disappears. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! More info: the thread doesn't have a runloop - the nsstream in question is using the main thread's runloop. I found the error in more detail: CFHash is getting called with NULL by CFReadStreamRead. Am i not allowed to read an nsstream by multiple threads even if the nsstream is declared atomic?

Comment: Hmmmm. Reading on a different thread than the socket's runloop sure sounds to me like something that's likely to turn out problematic. Did you find some documentation somewhere that explicitly states it to be safe?

Comment: No. But i have been doing it for years. Im relatively sure that this problem is not directly caused by that